# Integral $\int_{0}^{15} x^{10}e^{-x/3} \; dx.$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following definite integral with using integration by parts:
$$\int_{0}^{15} x^{10}e^{-x/3} \; dx.$$

Obviously it’s to be done (multiple times) with integration by parts by how would we do it without using parts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we know that:

$$\exp\left(x\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{x^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$x^\text{k}\exp\left(\text{p}x\right)=x^\text{k}\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\text{p}x\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{x^\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{p}x\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot x^{\text{k}+\text{n}}\tag2$$

So, when we integrate we get:

$$\mathcal{I}_\alpha\left(\text{k},\text{p}\right):=\int_0^\alpha x^\text{k}\exp\left(\text{p}x\right)\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\int_0^\alpha x^{\text{k}+\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\left[\frac{x^{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}}{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}\right]_0^\alpha=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}\cdot\left[x^{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}\right]_0^\alpha=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\alpha^{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}-0^{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}}{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\alpha^{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}}{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}=$$
$$\alpha^{1+\text{k}}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\alpha^\text{n}}{1+\text{k}+\text{n}}\tag3$$

> In your case we have $\alpha=15$, $\text{k}=10$ and $\text{p}=-\frac{1}{3}$. So:
>
> $$\mathcal{I}_{15}\left(10,-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\int_0^{15}x^{10}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{3}\right)\space\text{d}x=15^{1+10}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{15^\text{n}}{1+10+\text{n}}=$$
> $$15^{11}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{5^\text{n}}{11+\text{n}}\tag4$$

Comment: Just curious: why do you use \textrm{n} instead of n in math mode?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe That is something that I got used to do and have no specific reason for.

Answer (score 1):

$$I_0:=\int_0^{15}e^{-ax}dx=\frac{1-e^{-15a}}a.$$

Now differentiate ten times the RHS on $a$ and set $a=\dfrac13$.

[image]

---

We can draw a general formula. For ease, we address

$$I_0=\int_1^\infty e^{-ax}dx=\frac{e^{-a}}a$$

and by the Leibniz rule,

$$I_0^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^kk!}{a^{k+1}}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{n!}{k!}a^{-1-n+k}e^{-a}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}a^{-2-n}e^{-a}.$$

(Typos possible.)

Comment: Nice answer. It may make the calculations simpler if one first performs a simple change of varables and consider $3^{11} \int_0^5 t^{10} e^{ - t} dt$.

Comment: @Gary: I don't think I would use this method, anyway.